How to Properly Create the Data Architecture for a PERN Stack Application?
I'm building a web application using the PERN stack, and I'm looking for best practices on how to design the data architecture.
I just did a basic pernTODO in order to practice my postgressSQL skill a bit and honestly I felt quite confident. I spent a while creating a nice and "normalized" database for a little more practice on SQL.
Biggest mistake of my life. I have some of the biggest SQL queries I have seen. So far at least.
Which made me wonder if there is any way to solve this issue? Whats the best way or at least some different ways to design the data architecture when using an SQL. I have read about stored procedures but I don't know if they are worth it nor how to implement them.
I am using a client/server structure since I am using PERN but even when my backend has both a routing folder and controller for each endpoint I just feel like my files get too long.
Which made me wonder. How to Properly Create the Data Architecture for a PERN Stack Application?
These are some of my queries inside my controllers:
 const query = `
            SELECT
                pi.id AS person_id,
                pi.name AS person_name,
                pi.last_name AS person_last_name,
                j.id AS job_id,
                j.name AS job_name,
                j.description AS job_description,
                ri.id AS reference_id,
                ri.name AS reference_name,
                ri.last_name AS reference_last_name,
                ri.phone_number AS reference_phone_number,
                ri.email AS reference_email,
                pc.id AS personal_cellphone_id,
                pc.cell_phone_number AS personal_cell_phone_number,
                pe.id AS personal_email_id,
                pe.email AS personal_email
            FROM
                public.person_info pi
            LEFT JOIN
                public.job j ON pi.id = j.person_id
            LEFT JOIN
                public.reference_info ri ON j.id = ri.job_id
            LEFT JOIN
                public.personal_cellphone pc ON pi.id = pc.person_id
            LEFT JOIN
                public.personal_email pe ON pi.id = pe.person_id;
        `;

Also If someone knows somewhere to actually get good at designing databases or any good practice on SQL I would really appreciate it. Thank you for your time!

Given the information we have to go on (at the very least, it'd be good to see the table structure you came up with), your biggest mistake here is in thinking that was the biggest mistake of your life.
Again, can't be definitive without the table structure, but that looks like a good query; you could probably stand for some optimization, but the structure, the joins, etc. look perfectly fine to me.
(I will tell you, though, if you find yourself dealing with REALLY big databases, you'll look fondly back on this, sigh, and say "ah, he was so small back then...".)
As for resources, I'm a dinosaur and learned the trade back when most of us could only get online via BBSes that didn't connect to the wider internet, so I'm a fan of learning through books. And which books you go to depend entirely on which DBMS you're using. As a general rule of thumb, though, it's pretty hard to go wrong with Manning Publications. For basic, general SQL (though again every DBMS will have a slightly different dialect), SQL in a Month of Lunches is a good starting point. If you're leaning more towards architecture, Grokking Relational Database Design is right in your wheelhouse.
